# what will be the PID after fork()?

Tags: pid, fork

I am doing 3 consecutive forks in a C program.
1. Is it going to execute in the same order ?  ( My guess is yes ).
2. If I do a `pgrep myexecutable` from shell, would it give the process ids in the same order as they were started ? ( my guess is no, because you cant guarantee what pid the system gives the child, right ? )

Comment: It should not matter, for any reasonable program.

Comment: PID of last forked process is `$!` https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361436/6655092... I found this question while actually looking for `$!`, so I thought I'd post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shrinath, you should check the documentation for `fork()`, here it is:

```
Upon successful completion, fork() returns a value of 0 to the child
process and returns the process ID of the child process to the parent
process.  Otherwise, a value of -1 is returned to the parent process, no
child process is created, and the global variable errno is set to indi-
cate the error.
```

All that means for you, is that means your parent process will get the child's PID when it forks. The child knows it's the child, because `fork()` will return 0 to the child, so something like:

```
if((cpid = fork()))
{ 
  // This is the parent processs, child pid 
  // is in `cpid` variable
}else{
  // This is the child process, do your child
  // work here.
}
```

Beware for the chance that you get a minus number (so there's no child), you should check for that.

The output of `ps` will vary by system, but you should see an example, if you look at the whole tree (make your processes sleep, so you have time to check the `ps` output.)

Comment: Please go through the question again and tell me which part of the question isn't clear...  
I am not asking "how to create a child process", or "how will I know the pid of the child"... All I am asking is would it be in same order everytime ?   Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 5):

There would be a total of 8 processes running after 3 forks are executed

[image]

so now the pid would be depend on which order the child process are created by and also in which order the children of children are created.

could be like

```
main - 12345

child1_of_main_after_fork1  12346

child2_of_child1_after_fork2  12347

child3_of_main_after_fork2 12348

child4_of_main_after_fork3 12349

child5_of_child1_after_fork3 12350

child6_of_child2_after_fork3 12351

child7_of_child3_after_fork3 12352
```