# Why is $$ returning the same id as the parent process?

Tags: bash, shell, pid, subshell

I have problem with Bash, and I don't know why.
Under shell, I enter:

```
echo $$    ## print 2433
(echo $$)  ## also print 2433
(./getpid) ## print 2602
```

Where `getpid` is a C program to get current *pid*, like:

> ```
>    int main() {
>     printf("%d", (int)getpid());
>     return 0;
>    }
> ```

What confuses me is that:

1. I think "(command)" is a sub-process (am i right?), and i think its *pid* should be different with its *parent pid*, but they are the same, why...
2. When I use my program to show *pid* between parenthesis, the *pid* it shows is different, is it right?
3. Is `$$` something like macro?

Can you help me?

Comment: Note that `getpid` would show a different process ID even if it weren't run in a subshell.

Comment: @Marian `echo $$ $BASHPID ; ( echo $$ $BASHPID )` demonstrates that it does. Round brackets create a subshell. The statements may change variable values, and the parent shell must not see those changes. This is implemented as a `fork()` operation.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

`$$` is defined to return the process ID of the parent in a subshell; from the man page under "Special Parameters":

> $      Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell.

In `bash` 4, you can get the process ID of the child with `BASHPID`.

```
~ $ echo $$
17601
~ $ ( echo $$; echo $BASHPID )
17601
17634
```

Comment: "parent" is a bit misleading (at least it was to me), it's actually the "top level" shell. For instance : `echo $$; (echo $$; (echo $$))` echoes the same pid three times

Comment: Right; I should have said that the value is inherited from a parent shell (which inherited its value from *its* parent, etc). The top level shell sets it initially, rather than inheriting from its (non-shell) parent process.

Comment: `$ Expands to the process ID of the shell` does it tho? `echo $` just echoes the literal $.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Well, yes; `$` alone is not a parameter expansion. The man page is referring to the *name* of the special parameter, which is `$`; it's not claiming that `$` alone expands.

Comment: Ok I honestly have no idea what that means, but `echo $BASHPID` works in bash 4 and 5 (but not version 3.2.57 on MacOS)

Comment: All parameter expansions start with `$`, but `$` is also the name of one of the special parameters. `$`, `#`, `@`, `*`, etc are some of the special parameters; `$$`, `$#`, `$@`, `$*`, etc are the expressions that expand to the value of each.

Answer (score 85):

You can use one of the following.

- `$!` is the PID of the last backgrounded process.
- `kill -0 $PID` checks whether it's still running.
- `$$` is the PID of the current shell.

Comment: Shouldn't the second bullet be `kill -0 $!` if we're talking about background processes? `PID` isn't set to anything by default.

Answer (score 31):

1. Parentheses invoke a [subshell in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26064). Since it's only a subshell it might have the same PID - depends on implementation.
2. The C program you invoke is a separate process, which has its own unique PID - doesn't matter if it's in a subshell or not.
3. `$$` is an alias in Bash to [the current script PID](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID). See [differences between `$$` and `$BASHPID` here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#BASHPIDREF), and right above that the additional variable `$BASH_SUBSHELL` which contains the nesting level.

Answer (score 8):

Try `getppid()` if you want your C program to print your shell's PID.

Comment: Or if you use Rust just try `nix::unistd::getppid()` which will get the pid of current processes' parent - https://docs.rs/nix/0.18.0/nix/unistd/fn.getppid.html

Answer (score 4):

this one univesal way to get correct pid

`pid=$(cut -d' ' -f4 < /proc/self/stat)`

same nice worked for sub

```
SUB(){
    pid=$(cut -d' ' -f4 < /proc/self/stat)
    echo "$$ != $pid"
}

echo "pid = $$"

(SUB)
```

check output

```
pid = 8099
8099 != 8100
```

Comment: Nice idea, but won't that get you the pid of the fork the shell has run to capture the output of cut?  If I run it twice, once with echo $(...) and once without, then I get different answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you were asking how to get the PID of a known command it would resemble something like this:

If you had issued the command below
    #The command issued was ***

> dd if=/dev/diskx of=/dev/disky

---

**Then you would use:**

```
PIDs=$(ps | grep dd | grep if | cut -b 1-5)
```

What happens here is it pipes all needed unique characters to a field and that field can be echoed using

echo $PIDs

Answer (score 0):

if you want a simple shell script for getting the maximum PID with variable, do this

```
pid=$(cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max)
echo $pid
```

that will print you the maximum PID can be.

Comment: That is not the least bit relevant to this question

Answer (score 0):

#### Portable way of achieving that

```bash
get_own_pid() {
  # This function being called in a subshell,
  # it must returns the pid of the parent of the "cut" command parent
  cut -d' ' -f4 < /proc/self/stat \
    | xargs -I% sh -c 'cut -d" " -f4 < /proc/%/stat'
}

get_parent_pid() {
  # Same thing but repeating the last command once more to get the parent one level above
  cut -d' ' -f4 < /proc/self/stat \
    | xargs -I% sh -c 'cut -d" " -f4 < /proc/%/stat' \
    | xargs -I% sh -c 'cut -d" " -f4 < /proc/%/stat'
}


# Here pid is the same as the $$ pid because called from main process
MY_PID=$(get_own_pid)
echo "$$ == ${MY_PID}"

# Here called in a subprocess, the returned pid is different
(
  MY_CHILD_PID=$(get_own_pid)
  PARENT_PID_FROM_CHILD=$(get_parent_pid)
  echo "$$ != ${MY_CHILD_PID}"
  echo "$$ == ${PARENT_PID_FROM_CHILD}"
)
```

Inspired from [artem lapkin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57624140/8209615), thanks!