# Why $$ is not returning the PID of parent process?

Tags: bash

Consider file main.sh as

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "Main PID is $$"
CMD="./helper.sh"
echo $($CMD)
```

consider helper.sh as

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "PPID in helper script is $$"
echo "Bash pid is $BASHPID"
```

When I run `./main.sh` the output is

```
Main PID is 867
PPID in helper script is 868 Bash pid is 868
```

Now my query is that the command substitution used to run `helper.sh` from `main.sh` shoud've spawned a subshell which has its own PID which'll be returned by `$BASHPID` but `$$` must've returned the parent PID i.e. the pid of shell in which `main.sh` is running as is indicated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21063837).

So why is it not the case and parent pid is the same as current shell pid in `helper.sh` ?

Comment: `$$` is the process ID of the shell. What you want is `$PPID`, which is the process ID of the shell’s parent process.

Comment: Exactly that. `$$` and `$BASHPID` are only different when you're in a subshell. In the top level of a shell it's normal and expected for them to be identical. And while your `helper` is _run from_ a subshell, it is itself a whole new interpreter so you're in the top level within it when you do the echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected behavior for `$$` is to return the top-level PID of the current shell interpreter.

When you run `./helper.sh`, that's a new shell interpreter; **within its top level, `$$` and `$BASHPID` are expected to be identical**. (When you start a subshell within it, `$BASHPID` will change but `$$` will not).

Consider the following, expanded test case:

```
cat >main <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Main PID is $$"
(./helper "$$" "$BASHPID")
EOF

cat >helper <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Parent main PID is $1"
echo "Parent subshell PID is $2"
echo "Child main PID is $$"
echo "Child current PID is $BASHPID"
EOF

chmod +x main helper
./main
```

It should emit something like:

```
Main PID is 37596
Parent main PID is 37596
Parent subshell PID is 37597
Child main PID is 37597
Child current PID is 37597
```

The child's main PID is in this case the parent's subshell PID, because bash is able to recognize when it can directly `exec` a child process from inside a subshell. The child's *current* PID is the same as the child's main PID, because nothing that has been done that would create a new subshell inside the child; note that this optimization is contextually-dependent and may or may not happen, depending on traps and other active configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Duffy. There are two queries I still have in my mind 1.) Is creating a subshell different from a child process? 2.) How can we access the parent process Id directly in subshell without passing it as an argument? Will $PPID  works?

Comment: Use `$PPID` to get the PID of the parent process. And yes, subshells are a special case of child processes: They're different because they're divided by a `fork()` but without any `exec`-family syscall.